# Angular5 use Hostlistener and directive to highlight selected row

Tags: angular, event-handling, onclicklistener, angular5, angular-directive

Using Angular 5/2, I have created a table that pulls values from an array that exists in my TS file called "levels".

My HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="all" />
      </th>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Hourly Rate</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let level of levels ; let i = index">
      <td class="text-center">
         <input type="checkbox" 
          value="{{level.id}}"
          appHighlightOnCheck"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ level }}</td>
      <td>
         <input
         type="text"
         class="form-control">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input
         type="text"
         class="form-control">
       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When a checkbox is checked for a particular row, I want that row to have the class `active`, so it is highlighted.

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[appHighlightOnCheck]'
})
export class HighlightOnCheck implements OnInit{
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef){}

    ngOnInit(){console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode);

        if(this.elementRef.nativeElement.isChecked){
            this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode, 'active');  
        }
    }
}
```

isChecked doesn't seem to be the correct method. I have tried to implement other people's answers, but, being new to Angular 5 I am struggling.

Comment: Did you try just '.checked'?

Comment: @Powkachu I tried .checked, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I just copied your code to test it and found that you have an extra ' " ' in your input checkbox: appHighlightOnCheck". I don't know if it can causes a problem but anyway you can remove it.

Comment: If you really want to use a directive and not proceed like an answer below, you can add a HostListener. For example, @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() where you can check if it is checked or not. Because onInit is called just once. And the right property to check is .checked.

Comment: Thanks @Powkachu, I managed to achieve the functionality using the method you explained. The answer below seems to be slightly incorrect although it seems to be the most efficient method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done without directive. see if this helps:

`<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let level of levels ; let i = index" [class. active]="level.check?true:null">
      <td class="text-center">
         <input type="checkbox" 
          value="{{level.id}}"
          (change)="level.check = $event.target.checked"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ level }}</td>
      <td>
         <input
         type="text"
         class="form-control">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input
         type="text"
         class="form-control">
       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>`

Comment: Thanks, `[class. active]="level.check?true:null"` shouldn't have a space between class and active otherwise it throws an error. Also, this for me seems correct but it still doesn't add the class to the `<tr>`